# How to trace an output in Access back to the section of VBA code that produced it

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on updating an Access database with this year's new data. I did not write the code that goes along with it, and am trying to find out where the formula is for an output (ratios) that the VBA code produces. Is there a way to trace back where the output came from?

I've tried just doing CTRL F to find the word "ratio" in the code but it's so long I can't pin down exactly where it's coming from.

No error messages

Comment: There is no real way other than examining the VBA for code which seems related to the output.

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode you can step through the code step by step by pressing F8. You should be able to find the origin of every data export that way.
If the outputed data is a result of calculations I would check every query in the database. One of these probably takes care of those ratio's.